# How to implement nested list view with radio button , Each question have multiple radio button selection

Tags: listview, radio-button

I want to create survey screen which have multiple question with their multiple choice with radio button.

I want to create such type of screen in flutter

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.